# How can I find the values for $a$ and $b$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt {ax +b} - 2}{x} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the values for $a$ and $b$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt {ax +b} - 2}{x} = 1$?

Please, don´t use derivatives.

I´ve given my own solution for this problem below. But I don´t think it´s the most elegant one.

Comment: it's the most standard way to do it, I wouldn't count on anything very different. also - you should've included your thoughts in the question itself, not as a separate answer since you're still looking for a different one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt {ax +b} - 2}{x} = 1$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt {ax +b} - 2}{x} * x = 1 * x$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt {ax +b} - 2 = \lim_{x \to 0} x$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt {0x +b} - 2 = 0$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt {b} - 2 = 0$    $\displaystyle \Rightarrow$    $b=4$

from that we have

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt {ax +4} - 2}{x} = 1$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt {ax +4} - 2}{x} * \frac{\sqrt {ax +4} + 2}{\sqrt{ax +4} + 2} $

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{{ax +4} - 4}{(x)(\sqrt{ax +4} + 2)}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ax}{(x)(\sqrt{ax +4} + 2)}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{\sqrt{ax +4} + 2} = 1$   so

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} {a} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{ax +4} + 2$

$\displaystyle a = \sqrt{0a +4} + 2$

$\displaystyle a = 4$

Awnser: $a=4$ and $b=4$

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the limit as below $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ax+b-4}{x\left(\sqrt{ax+b}+2\right)}$$Now, it is clear that $a>0,b>0$, because if one of them is negative (both of them cannot be together negative, obviously), then you can make $x$ small enough to make $ax+b<0$. Now, $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sqrt{ax+b}+2\right)=\sqrt{b}+2$. Then your problem becomes to find $a,b>$ such that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ax+b-4}{x}=\sqrt{b}+2\\\Rightarrow a+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{b-4}{x}=\sqrt{b}+2$$This implies that $b$ must be equal to $4$ and hence $a=2+2=4$.

Answer (score 1):

1). You need $\sqrt{ax+b}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}2$. Can you justify why? What does that impose for $b$?

2). You can then use  the fact that
$\sqrt{1+t} = 1+\frac{t}{2} +o(t)$ (when $t\to 0$) to see what the numerator becomes -- call that $A$ (after (1), it will only depend on $x$ and $a$). To get your overall limit, you then need to set $a$ such that
$$
\frac{A}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 1
$$
This will give you the only possible value for $a$.